# How to .strip all emails in a rails database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I have a batch invite command where users can enter a bunch of emails to invite people to an account in my app. However, up until now, it was including one space at the front of every e-mail...

I've since added a .strip for every new email, but I now want to update all previously created accounts.

I am running the app on heroku, so I'd imagine it will be a command at the heroku console, I just don't want to feck it up, so I'm asking for help here.

Nevermind, I figured it out.

```
     User.all.each do |user|; user.update_attributes(:email => user.email.split); end
```

That was the solution. Just a little tricky figuring out that Heroku only works with one line at a time, unlike the actual rails console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can execute SQL via the rails console. Try

begin; update users set email = trim(email); commit;